# How to tell when code is running in console and Source

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

[image]This isn't a question about code-my apologies, I'm just not sure where to ask it...

When I run code that takes time in markdown, the console section has a STOP button which I use to tell me if my code is still running (if the stop button is visible-it is still running).

The folder list where I keep my script is very long, so I keep having to drag over the Console button to make it bigger so that I can see if the code is still running. I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way of seeing if my code is still running rather than looking to see if the stop button is visible?
2. Is there a way of hiding the various folders that my document is in so that I can easily see the stop button without having to make that Console section bigger?

There used to be a red bar in the source pane that progressed vertically down the chunk I was running, but it is gone!

Comment: May you share a screenshot of your workspace?